# RewriteRule http_host is ignored?

Tags: .htaccess

A web account has different domains connected but only domain1.com is reachable with https. So I'd like to send all domains to https://www.domain1.com.

My idea was to have a rule which checks for port 443 first.
If not used it leads to https://www.domain1.com.
But if https is already used and domain name is different, then rewrite to https://www.domain1.com, too.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://www.domain1.com [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.domain1.com [R=301,L]
```

First Rule (443) works, but the other does not. If one of the additional domains is called with https://, then browser shows message about unsafe domain, as SSL certificate is for wrong domain.

What's wrong?

Comment: URL rewrite happens after SSL handshake so this warning cannot be addressed by rewrites.

Comment: Is there any way to do it?